# What is the reason for prefixing unused parameters with an underscore (_)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js app where I have a `GET` method on root ('/') that has a request and a response parameter on the callback function. I am making use of the response parameter, however, I am not using the request parameter.

I am using Visual Studio Code, and the linter has suggested to add an underscore as a prefix to my request parameter.

Why should I add an underscore prefix to an unused parameter?

[image: VS Code Linter suggesting parameter underscore prefix]

Comment: Very likely just a convention thing. Single unused parameters are often named as just `_`, and personally, private members start with underscore. It doesn't look like it has any semantic relevance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main purpose is to inform yourself or other programmers in the future that even though this callback method takes two parameters, I don't need the first one, in your case the req parameter. It slightly improves readability and the intention of your code.

Comment: I know of an underscore being used to represent private members as mentioned by ASDFGerte, but is this convention or just something to be courteous for future developers?

Comment: As ASDFGerte mentioned usually for parameters it's just an underscore, not sure why it was recommended as prefix, just a convention, you don't have to use it, but in my personal experience I find it helps readibility when reading code since if I saw req instead mentally I start thinking what is this parameter representing, but if I see underscore I just ignore it

Answer (score 0):

I have this situation in a ES6 module I am exporting. VS Code linter also suggested the underscore on the unused parameter. If I don't include the parameter, I get an error in the imported file. Adding the underscore, the parameter is no longer grayed out. As if it was used in the function it is applied to. One more little pearl of wisdom in JavaScript to hang on to ......